# Definition of calculation in the column DAX SQL

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax

I have a table:

| ID | Values | Calculation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Base Value |  |
| 2 | Interest Total | 1 + 3 + 4 |
| 3 | Interest for Late Payment | 2/4 |
| 4 | Interest on Arrears |  |
| 5 | Interest Rate |  |

In the calculation column I have a definition how the values should be calculated, e.g.
Interest Total is sum of ID 1, 3 and 4 and Interest for Late Payment.

I need to create calculations to show all values in Power BI report. I don't want to do it manually. Do you know any way how it can be calculated?

Comment: What is wrong with creating measure for each one?

Comment: It's only example. I have more than 100 rows with definitions. Some definitions contain more than 50 calculations.

Comment: You have created the measures already and you want to create another based on the definition or you are at the beginning and trying to figure out how to handle that?

Comment: No, measures are not created. I have a fact table which contains only base numbers (in my above example it's ID 1,4 and 5), but definition to calculate 2 and 3 is in the column (text format). I'm wondering how can I deal with it and create measures to calculate values based on the definition in "Calculation" column.

Comment: You have to do it manually from the very beginning. This is a standard and common scenario. In most of the complex reports, there are dozens or even hundreds of measures. Create an empty table to hold all your measures to improve work and readability